# How to limit memory usage when I run Memgraph Platform within Docker?

Tags: docker, graph-databases, memgraphdb

I've been running Memgraph for a few days now and everything is working as expected. This is the first time that I'm using Docker.

I've noticed that when I shut down the Memgraph Platform my RAM is still used. I need to restart my computer to free up my RAM. Is there some switch that I can use to limit the memory that Memgraph Platform uses? Is there some way to release the memory after I shut it down?

If it is important, my OS is Windows 10 Professional and I have a 6 years old laptop with 8GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is not related to Memgraph, but Docker or to WSL2 to be more precise. You say that you use Windows 10 so I presume your Docker is [configured to use WSL2](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/).

You didn't write which exact build of Windows 10 you are using, but depending on it WSL can use [up to 80% of your RAM if you don't limit it](https://www.aleksandrhovhannisyan.com/blog/limiting-memory-usage-in-wsl-2/).

When you run the Docker image you will see a process called [vmmem](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180717-00/?p=99265). When you shutdown running Docker image this process will still occupy your RAM. Restarting your computer frees up the RAM, which is what you are experiencing.

The solution is not to change the configuration of your Memgraph, but to configure Docker. You need to [limit the amount of memory that WSL2 can use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config). But be careful; this is a change that will affect all of your WSL2 instances, not just the Docker ones.

The exact steps that you need to do are:

1. Shutdown all of the WSL instances with `wsl --shutdown`
2. Edit the `.wslconfig` file (it is located in your user profile folder)

Add the following lines to it:

```
[wsl2]
memory=3GB
```

This will limit the RAM usage of WSL to 3GB. I hope that this will help you.